# Problems with getting real size of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, element

I have a canvas element:

```
<canvas id='arena'></canvas>
```

The Element has exactly the size of the website window. It is inside a div Element, and both are 100% size.
I tried this command:

```
var c = document.getElementById('arena');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
console.log(c.width+'  '+c.height);
```

The ouput is 300   150.
I looked in the console, and it said the canvas is 2000*1000px
So what is wrong with this code?

Comment: do you have css styles applied to it? the css width / height will stretch/shrink the actual canvas, instead of setting those dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to specify width and height attributes while defining canvas like:

```
<canvas id="arena" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

While using javascript, px usage is not preferred:

```
var c = document.getElementById('arena');
c.width=300;
c.height=150;
```